# Tutorial - Error after adding style

Tags: node.js, meteor, reactjs

I am doing Meteor + React tutorial on Meteor Official website(https://www.meteor.com/tutorials/react/components), but after adding the style the console gives me the following warning:

> Unable to resolve some modules:

```
"react-native" in /Users/myuser/Development/simple-todos/client/main.js (web.browser)
```

> If you notice problems related to these missing modules, consider running:

```
meteor npm install --save react-native
```

My localhost is displaying the styled background **without** the todoList, which was shown before it.

**EDIT:**

I really forgot to do this step here: Second, delete client/main.js and create three new files

Comment: Have you tried running the recommended command?

Comment: Please show your `main.js` file

Answer (score 1):

Check that you dont have import from 'react-native' in your main.js
React native is for mobile not web.

Comment: I really forgot to do this step here: _Second, delete client/main.js and create three new files:_